# res subolder ("R") not found ("R cannot be resolved to a variable")

Tags: android

This is my first attempt at an Android app. I'm targeting Android 4/Ice Cream Sandwich.

When trying to run the app, I get the err msg "R cannot be resolved to a variable" on this line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Yet main.xml IS there, below \res\layout\ as it should be.

What might the problem be with this as-yet as-minimal-as-possible app (the only code it has so far has been auto-generated)?

Comment: OK, it's running (sort of). I had a mismatch of target/minimum APIs. Once I fixed that and restarted Elipse, it generated the necessary files under \gen (R). However, then the emulator croaked.

Comment: Are you using an IDE with a default project, or command line tools? Most IDEs' skeleton app will compile R into the same package as your skeleton activity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"R cannot be resolved to a variable" comes when: 
a)you mismatch your sdk version
B) there are errors on any of your layouts, which makes the auto-generated R files not to be created
C) Other issues are usually solved by cleaning the project

Comment: This will also happen if the package name in your manifest does not match the package name.  This is not fixed by cleaning, and has to be changed manually.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your import clauses and see if the import for the "R" class is there. What dev environment are you using?

Comment: Eclipse Indigo - I had to avail myself of the Quick Fix to add this for it to compile: - wow, this is really irritating that hitting Enter posts the message. import com.axx3AndSpace.R;

Answer (score 1):

If you already cleaned and builded your project and if the problem is not solved,

1. Check the name of your xml files. It should not contain any capital letters.
2. Just after cleaning the project, check the console screen, it can be xml problems which program can be compiled with them before. (XML problems like Bad Block etc.) Clean those lines, and after success, write them again.

Answer (score 1):

A simple step that worked for me:

Navigate to gen[Generated Java Files].If you can find the R.java file, double click to open the file. Save and close it. The error related to R variable in the main activity seems to disappear for me.